# How to tell OkHttpClient to ignore cache and force refresh from server?

Tags: android, caching, retrofit, okhttp

In my android application, I am using Retrofit with OkHttpClient with caching enabled to access some APIs. Some of our APIs sometimes return empty data. We provide a "Refresh" button in the app for the client to reload data from a specific API.

How do I tell OkHttpClient that a specific request should ignore the cached entry. Alternatively, is there a mechanism to delete the cached response corresponding to a single request?

I see Cache.remove(request) method but it is marked as private.

Answer (score 31):

As Jake Wharton suggested in [issues](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1496), do this to ignore the cache:

```
request.setCacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK);
```

Comment: I was using an older version, updated to 3.4 and your solution working. Thanks inder

Comment: is it able to set the cacheControl from OkHttpClient class, not from the Request class?

Comment: Yes - to disable caching globally, create the client with a null cache: `new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().cache(null).build();`

Comment: Is it possible to annotate some API calls to not use the cache at all ?

Comment: This does not work if you use the Coroutines Adapter. Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 7):

```
@Headers("Cache-Control: no-cache")
```

on the method should work. 
If you want to do it dynamically you can add a

```
@Header("Cache-Control")
```

String cacheControl parameter and pass null or "no-cache"