# Want to bypass header match in OkHttp cache

Tags: java, caching, okhttp, outputcache

**OkHttp3** uses this method in it's cache class to match request and cached responses, my problem is sometimes I don't like to match headers, just URL is fair enough. How can I bypass header matching (comparison) in Cache class? For example maybe I like to accept cached items from previous authentication, while currently token is expired, so **I don't like to match tokens**.

```
public boolean matches(Request request, Response response) {
      return url.equals(request.url().toString())
          && requestMethod.equals(request.method())
          && HttpHeaders.varyMatches(response, varyHeaders, request);
    }
```

Comment: As per my understanding, already answered here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053156/how-to-tell-okhttpclient-to-ignore-cache-and-force-refresh-from-server